# How to get rid of default margin around image inside a div?

Tags: html, css, image

I am building a few websites and always have this same problem with css.

I have two images inside a div container.

When i put for example a text inside a div the div takes the heigth of the text but when i put an image in for some for me unknown reason the div suddenly seems to have a default heigth.

As you can see i have made the size of the images responsive in my css. I ve involved a color on the div just to give a clearer look on what happens.

When i narrow my browser screen the heigth of the div stays equal ( thus not being responsive) and for some reason the images are pushed down inside the div.

1. How can i solve this.I want the div container height to be responsive as the images inside are and holding the same height as the images and as i narrow the browser screen.
2. Last but not least ... what is it that i do not understand ?

Thank you for helping me out.

My code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title></title>

</head>

<body>

<div style="background-color:red;">
<img style="height:2vw; width:4vw;" src="image.jpg" alt="en">   
<img style="height:2vw; width:4vw;" src="image.jpg" alt="en">   
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please provide more code. i think in css add this overflow:hidden and img- width:100%.

Comment: Please provide the css and html code

Comment: i d like to but the system  does not want to show it

Comment: I already edit this. You can Approve. First you need to know how to ask in stackoverflow and also add language identifier to highlight code.

Comment: i have seen your edit and approved it. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent div to have a certain size, you should enforce dimension on the div and inherit its properties to its children...

```
div{
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background: red;
}

div>img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
<div>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="text">
</div>
```

Comment: The width simply is the width of the screen which is the default width. But i have applied what you suggested to the height. Gave the div the height of 2vw and the img a heigth of 100%. But when i narrow the screen the image still drops down and goed even outside and below the div

Comment: Then simply set `overflow:hidden` on the div ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. I think it will help you. [codepen](https://codepen.io/romiul/pen/WWZovW)

```css
    div{background-color:red;width:200px;overflow:hidden;}
    div img{height:auto; max-width:100%;display:block;}
```

```html
    <div>
        <img src="image" alt="text">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try adding `display: block;` to `<img>` tag.

I hope this help.

If you aren't using Bootstrap or another css framework, maybe you need to add reset.css file to your project. Example of reset: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Combined with the reply of BJRINT above i have solved the problem. Thank you very much both. I do not use any framework btw.

Comment: Actually your solution was sufficient to solve it without the solution proposed by BJRIN. Now i still try to understand why display:block needs to be added to keep the img inside the div container.

Comment: The use of a reset.css gives you a unified behavior accross browsers. Images tags where once used in the middle of paragraphs in older html pages. If you try to put and image tag in the middle of a text with a default `ìnline` property it will not break text flow.
The block property actually adds newlines at the beginning and end of a nested element, and turns them into "blocks", which means they are parent sized by default (window size if they are at document root). You can get more info on the [display property on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-outside)

Comment: I'm really happy that it works!! I usually add <figure> before <img> tag, because using reset.css file it will add display:block in figure automatically.

Comment: Thanks again for all the info Alba Silvente Fuentes. I have been using reset css and should indeed consider using it again. Most certainly because i am a backend guy. CSS gives me the creeps to be honest.

Answer (score -1):

Try using **max-width:100%** on the image. This will keep it's size limited to it's parent size.

Comment: Thank you but i have no problems with the width - the width is doing fine and exactly what i expect it to do

Comment: neither is there a problem with the height or the width of the image - the image in both dimensions is doing fine and doing exactly what i expect it to do. The problem is in the div container and the positioning inside the div container and also the responsivness of the div container